# Django admin panel does't work correctly on Debug=False on production

Tags: django, django-admin

I can't add or delete items when Debug = False on production. On Debug = True everything is fine.

Screenshot when Debug = True:

[image: debug = true]

Screenshot when Debug = False:

[image: debug = false]

Code from models.py:

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
    miniaturka=models.FileField(blank=False)
    logo=models.FileField(blank=True)
    nazwa=models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False)
    link=models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    grafika=models.FileField(blank=True)
    grafika_mobilna=models.FileField(blank=True) 
    opis=models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name="Portfolio"
        verbose_name_plural="Portfolio"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazwa

class PortfolioRow(models.Model):
    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    portfolioRowType = models.ForeignKey(PortfolioRowType, null=True, blank=True, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo1 = models.FileField(blank=True)
    photo2 = models.FileField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.portfolio.nazwa

class PortfolioVideo(models.Model):
    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.portfolio.nazwa
```

Code from admin.py:

```
from typing import List
from django.contrib import admin
from main.models import *

class PortfolioRowAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = PortfolioRow

class PortfolioVideoAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = PortfolioVideo

@admin.register(Portfolio)
class PortfolioAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PortfolioRowAdmin, PortfolioVideoAdmin]

    class Meta:
        model = Portfolio
```

Comment: Are you sure you are logged in as superuser on the production site? It looks like a user with admin access but only "view" permission.

Comment: yes, i'm logged as superuser

Comment: And what happens if you set `DEBUG=False` on the local development machine (localhost)?

Comment: On localhost it always works

Comment: And this is the actual code, not a "cleaned up" version? I'm asking because there does not appear to be anything in there that could explain the issue.

Comment: Yes, just removed other models not related to this problem

Comment: The top  image shows `portfolio/add/`, whereas the bottom image shows `portfolio/13/change/`. I assume you also compared the same paths?

Comment: in one case i added new item and in the other i changed already existing one, but it doesn't matter

Comment: Have you tried logging out and logging back in, clearing caches, session cookies, etc.? Did you check the user admin to make sure you do not have any `groups` or special user `permissions` set up for the user that is logged-in on the production side? (just to be thorough)

Comment: yes, no groups, all permissions, same problem in incognito, but when I turn on Debug it magically works :/